# Getting rid of both #N/A and 0 values in a single cell

Tags: excel

I know the function =IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,0))=0,"",VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,0))
will blank out cells that return vlookup values of 0

and the function =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,FALSE),"") will do the same thing for #N/A errors, but is there a way to do all in a single formula?

The data I'm using is returning both 0 and #N/A because I have account numbers that are missing as well as account numbers that have no information in the return column.

Sorry about not posting a screen shot but my reputation is not high enough yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think once-through method would do it, no need to "pretest" the answer, but I only use this when the lookup returns text answers.

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,0)&""

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,0)&"", "")
```

If your values are numeric, then your original syntax is fine, here they are merged into one:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,0))=0, "", VLOOKUP(E1,A2:B10,2,0)), "")
```